# PHP Resource for getting combinations of x distinct items in y distinct bins?

Tags: php, math, combinations

Does anyone know a resource (manual or book) or have the PHP solution for getting all the combinations of x distinct items in y distinct bins?
For example, if I had 2 items [1, 2] with 2 bins, the 4 possibilities would be:

`[ 1,2 ] [ ]
 [ 1 ] [ 2 ]
 [ 2 ] [ 1 ]
 [ ] [ 1,2 ]`

I need the combinations, not permutations, as order of items is irelevent. And there is no min/max for items in a bin. And if you're going to downgrade my question because it's unclear, please specify what you're confused with. I've spent the entire day trying to find a solution, even in another programming language. Apparently, not very easy to come up with.

UPDATE: Hi Karol, thanks for the comment and link. I'm still working away on this, and did find that page in my searches and converted that to PHP here:

```
function combinationsOf($k, $xs){
if ($k === 0)
    return array(array());
if (count($xs) === 0)
    return array();
$x = $xs[0];
$xs1 = array_slice($xs,1,count($xs)-1);
$res1 = combinationsOf($k-1,$xs1);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($res1); $i++) {
    array_splice($res1[$i], 0, 0, $x);
}
$res2 = combinationsOf($k,$xs1);
return array_merge($res1, $res2); }
```

I'm going about it in a different way with this than what I originally hoped for, so still hoping to hear from someone ... thanks!

UPDATE: So I'm making progress, making use of the above recursive function along with another link I found: [Permutation Of Multidimensional Array in PHP](http://www.namasteui.com/permutation-of-multidimensional-array-in-php/)
Although, correct me if I'm wrong (it's been a loooong day), but it's not permutations, but combinations, that's being generated here.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) method which utilizes recursion. Basically, it's like a "smart brutforce" approach which takes a path and tries to get combinations which work.

The solution may look a little large but most of the functions are there just to support the `combo` function. The main brains behind the algorithm is behind the `combo` function which creates the combinations. The rest of the functions are there to support the `combo` function and print a nice looking output.

```
<?php
function toPlainArray($arr2) {
    $output = "[";
    foreach($arr2 as $arr) {
        $output .= "[";
        foreach($arr as $val) {
            $output .= $val . ", ";
        }
        if($arr != []) {
            $output = substr($output, 0, -2) . "], ";
        } else {
            $output .= "], ";
        }   
    }
    return substr($output, 0, -2) . "]";
}

function difference($arr2d, $arr1d) {
    foreach((array)$arr2d as $arr) {
        foreach($arr as $item) {
            if(in_array($item, $arr1d)) {
                $index = array_search($item, $arr1d);
                unset($arr1d[$index]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $arr1d;
}

function getNextPossibleSol($pSol, $item) { // returns an array (1d)
    $allItems = range(1, $item);
    return difference($pSol, $allItems); 
}

function createEmpty2dArray($arr, $amount) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
        $arr[] = [];
    }
    return $arr;
}


function isSmallerThenPartialItems($item, $pSol) {
    foreach($pSol as $arr) {
        foreach($arr as $val) {
            if($val > $item) return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function combo($items, $buckets, $partialSol=[]) {
     if($partialSol == []) { // Starting empty array, populate empty array with other arrays (ie create empty buckets to fill)
         $partialSol = createEmpty2dArray($partialSol, $buckets);
     }

    $nextPossibleSol = getNextPossibleSol($partialSol, $items);

    if($nextPossibleSol == []) { // base case: solution found
        echo toPlainArray($partialSol); // 2d array
        echo "<br /><br />";
    } else {
        foreach($nextPossibleSol as $item) {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($partialSol); $i++) {
                if(isSmallerThenPartialItems($item, $partialSol)) { // as order doesn't matter, we can use this if-statement to remove duplicates
                    $partialSol[$i][] = $item;
                    combo($items, $buckets, $partialSol);
                    array_pop($partialSol[$i]);
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}

combo(2, 2); // call the combinations functions with 2 items and 2 buckets

?>
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], []]

[[1], [2]]

[[2], [1]]

[[], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you Nick! I had a doctor's appointment this morning, but I will be back on shortly to test it out and mark it as 'accepted' and answered/solved.

Comment: Awesome, no worries

Comment: Lol, looks like it works, but that output I provided was just to make it clear to the viewer what I meant. I would've thought by a 'return $partialSol' instead of calling the toPlainArray() function, I would've gotten the actual PHP array, which is what I need. Maybe I need to pass the $partialSol array by reference everywhere and then I can access that array with: combo(2, 3, $result) ? Any quick ideas on which is easier?

Comment: Hey, so would you like the function to return a 2d array like the one it is printing?

Comment: yeppers, that would be a bonus. Really a 'y' dimensional array, where 'y' is the number of bins. Otherwise, I'll try to figure it out myself, but you know your code better. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeT Ah, well, if you want to do it in a fairly simple way you can declare `$solutions=[];` above the `combo` function, and then on the 1st line of the `combo` function write `global $solutions;`, then instead of `echo toPlainArray();`  you can add the line `$solutions[] = partialSol;`. Lastly on the very last line of the function add `return $solutions;`. The combo function will now return an array of results instead of printing them